# Ubuntu - Nginx + php5-fpm - suddenly times out every request even after restart

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, ubuntu-12.04

Caveat - Newbie nginx/php5-fpm/ubuntu

I inherited a couple linux boxes and have had the same thing happen on both.  I assume it's user error, but for the life of me I don't know what I did.

Symptoms:  server working ok nginx to php5-fpm and back.
I run a cookbook (made by others) that go some git gyrations, sym links, etc. and composure updates.
Generally things just work.

The most recent time, I wasn't seeing my latest code be served up (or perhaps cached somewhere??) and I did a sudo service php5-fpm restart.

After this last time, nothing goes through.  NGINX complains of time outs on ever single call:
2016/02/09 16:06:26 [error] 24102#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: yyy.yyyy.com, request: "GET /v2/phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "yyy.yyyy.com"

I've restarted php5-fpm and nginx.
I've updated configs for both to go to 127.0.0.1:9000 and demonstrated in each of the respective log files that they switched over.  I then switched them back to the unix sock listed above.

I'm at a complete loss as to why they don't seem to hook up.

And I don't think I did anything other than restart php5-fpm.  Does it matter which directory I'm in when I restarted php5-fpm?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

EDIT:  I confirmed that the *.sock file disappeared when I went to the port 9000 and reappeared when I reconfigured.  I even renamed the .sock file to test it, in case it mattered.

EDIT:  PHP5-fpm log doesn't show much:
[10-Feb-2016 09:12:20] WARNING: [pool www] child 26295 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 1383.735723 seconds from start
[10-Feb-2016 09:12:20] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26346 started

from apport.log:
is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment

Comment: Check the web application.

Comment: Check the application and php logs, post any relevant contents. Directory makes no difference to service restart.

Comment: @MichaelHampton...  Apache2 is installed but not running.  This is an API only machine.  It should just receive and serve up php files for JSON consumption.  I don't know if there are other pieces I'm missing.  What 'web application'?  I'm hitting this with Postman JSON requests or even just trying to serve up phpinfo.php.

Comment: @Tim, what other logs should I look into?  I only know the nginx and php5-fpm.

Comment: You don't just run PHP, you run an application written in PHP. Probably not relevant, but worth looking at. Given the core dump I might reinstall, but I'm not really an expert in this area. What does google say when you search for "SIGSEGV php5" or "SIGSEGV php5-fpm"?

Comment: Tracking this down, the closest I've found is the apport error and crash file:
is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
Is there a chance I did something by doing an SUDO service restart as non-root when the service was running as root?
NOTE:  api code (app) was running just fine until apparently I did a restart on the PHP5-FPM service and now it's in this stuck state.

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out to be xdebug configuration.  I'd been working to enable xdebug a few days ago to no avail.  Nothing was even taking effect (affect?)

Last night it hit me that perhaps xdebug was hanging.  I commented out the xdebug configuration, restarted PHP5-fpm and things freed up.

I, unfortunately, didn't see anything in any of the logs to point to XDEBUG config.